# Extract rating from google search results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to extract google search results using google api in python.I am able to extract url, link, title and snippet. But i also want to extract the rating that is displayed in the google search results.
Below is the code i am using:

```
    #Google Search Function

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term,  cx=cse_id,start = 1,hq ='company reviews', **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search('Swiggy', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
print(results[2]["title"])
print(results[2]["link"])
print(results[2]["displayLink"])
print(results[2]["snippet"])
```

I can see the first search result, on searching "swiggy company review" on google, shows rating of 3.7 but i don't know how to extract that information.Can anyone please suggest any solution? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the relevant response code (results)?

Comment: the result i am getting is:
Working at Swiggy | Glassdoor
https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-Swiggy-EI_IE952680.11,17.htm
www.glassdoor.com
b"Aug 14, 2015 ... See what employees say it's like to work at Swiggy. Salaries ... 226 Reviews  4 \nJobs ... Swiggy CEO &amp; Co-Founder Sriharsha Majety."
Aug 14, 2015 ... See what employees say it's like to work at Swiggy. Salaries ... 226 Reviews · 4 
Jobs ... Swiggy CEO &amp; Co-Founder Sriharsha Majety.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google API has been deprecated, it could be easily done scraping it using `BeautifulSoup` `CCS` selector `select()` (for multiple elements) / `select_one()` (for specific element) methods amoung other techniques.

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Search-Results-Review#main.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get(
  'https://www.google.com/search?q=swiggy company review',
  headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

# Selects just one Review element (using converted xPath to CSS selector):
# review = soup.select_one('#rso > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > span:nth-of-type(1)').text
# print(review)

# Selects just one Vote element (using converted xPath to CSS selector):
# votes = soup.select_one('#rso > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > span:nth-of-type(2)').text
# print(votes)

data = []

# Selects multiple Vote elements:
for something in soup.select('.uo4vr'):
    rating = something.select_one('.uo4vr g-review-stars+ span').text.split(':')[1].strip()
    votes_reviews = something.select_one('.uo4vr span+ span').text.split(' ')[0]

    data.append({
      "Rating": rating,
      "Votes/Reviews": votes_reviews,
    })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Rating": "4",
    "Votes/Reviews": "1,219"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "4",
    "Votes/Reviews": "1,090"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "3.8",
    "Votes/Reviews": "46"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "3.8",
    "Votes/Reviews": "260"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "4.1",
    "Votes/Reviews": "1,047"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "3.3",
    "Votes/Reviews": "47"
  },
  {
    "Rating": "1.5",
    "Votes/Reviews": "114"
  }
]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "swiggy company review",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# For extracting single elements:
# rating = results['organic_results'][0]['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['rating']
# print(f"Rating: {rating}")

# votes = results['organic_results'][0]['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['votes']
# print(f"Votes: {votes}")


# For extracing multiple elements:
data = []

for organic_result in results['organic_results']:

  title = organic_result['title']

  try:
    rating = organic_result['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['rating']
  except: 
    rating = None
  
  try: 
    votes = organic_result['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['votes']
  except:
    votes = None

  try: 
    reviews = organic_result['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['reviews']
  except:
    reviews = None

  data.append({
    "Title": title,
    "Rating": rating,
    "Votes": votes,
    "Reviews": reviews,
  })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Title": "Swiggy Reviews | Glassdoor",
    "Rating": 4,
    "Votes": 1219,
    "Reviews": null
  },
  {
    "Title": "Ride.Swiggy: 254 Employee Reviews | Indeed.com",
    "Rating": null,
    "Votes": null,
    "Reviews": null
  }
  {
    "Title": "Working at Swiggy | Glassdoor",
    "Rating": 4,
    "Votes": 1090,
    "Reviews": null
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.